# Why isn't iPhone Mail working right with Google Apps Email?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, gmail

I am having a big problem with my iPhone's Mail App. For some reason, emails are not going to my iPhone. I have all of my settings right and I have IMAP on in settings and this still keeps popping up:

[image: iPhone screenshot]

I followed all of the steps on [this page](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77702) for Google Apps users and nothing will work, this used to work and all of a sudden it quit working. I have a lot of emails that are coming to my email account online but my iPhone mail hasn't been working for a while now. (hence the last update at the bottom in my screenshot above, *9/5/11*)

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the account?

Comment: @Moshe Yeah, I will try again though...

Comment: @Moshe Okay, it looks like it worked. (for now anyway, it might start up that problem again someday) Thanks :D

Comment: Great, I'm going to post as an answer then, please accept if that worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried removing the account and then adding it again? (This may help if some setting has become corrupted. doing so will force iOS to start a "fresh slate" for the account.)